# proof of $\|a+b\|_2\le\|a\|_2+\|b\|_2$

Tags: analysis, inequality, reference-request, triangle-inequality

I try to prove $\|a+b\|_2\le\|a\|_2+\|b\|_2$.Where$\|\cdot\|_2=(\sum |x_i|^2)^{1/2}$.a,b can be bounded sequences or n-dimentional vectors take value on $\mathbb{C}$.

My first try is to see if for each term, $|a_i+b_i|^2\le|a_i|^2+|b_i|^2$. This seems to be wrong when $ab<0$.

I know that $|a+b|\le|a|+|b|$ and $|\sum _{1}^{n}a_ib_i|\le(\sum _{1}^{n}|a_i|^2)^{1/2}(\sum _{1}^{n}|b_i|^2)^{1/2} $. But I am not sure how to prove when the right hand side is addition instead of product.

And I think I don't quite understand the general logic behind these inequalities, so I always have troubles proving similar inequalities. Could anyone tell me some good english reference books about this topic?

Comment: As written the inequality is false, as you can see by taking $a=b$.  What's true is $\Vert a+b \Vert_2 \leq \Vert a \Vert_2 + \Vert b \Vert_2$.

Comment: Let's do it for the series. We have $$ \Vert a + b \Vert_2^2 = \sum (a_n + b_n)^2 \leq \sum a_n^2 + \sum b_n^2 + 2 \sum \vert a_n b_n \vert \leq  \sum a_n^2 + \sum b_n^2 + 2 \left(\sum a_n^2\right)^{1/2}\left( \sum b_n^2 \right)^{1/2} = \Vert a \Vert_2^2 + \Vert b \Vert_2^2 + 2 \Vert a \Vert_2 \Vert b \Vert_2 = (\Vert a \Vert_2+\Vert b \Vert_2)^2.$$ Now take the square root and be ready to be amazed.

Comment: I am not sure that the first inequality is correct because the definition of the norm is the square of absolute value, not the original summation. This is where I was stuck when I tried ealier.

Comment: It is correct for sequences with real entries. For complex entries just take the absolute value (it makes no difference for the idea). Also if you wish to message somebody, you should use @SeverinSchraven (in my case), otherwise I will not be notified :)

Comment: I see where I was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you write an answer yourself. Then the next person can profit from your insight.

Answer (score 1):

$$\Vert a+b \Vert^2 = \langle  a+b,a+b \rangle  = \langle a,a \rangle +\langle  b,b \rangle +\langle a,b \rangle + \langle b,a \rangle $$
By Cauchy-Schwartz inequality,
$$ \leq  \Vert a \Vert^2+\Vert b \Vert^2 +\Vert a \Vert \Vert b \Vert+\Vert a\Vert \Vert b \Vert \leq \left(\Vert a \Vert+\Vert b \Vert \right)^2 $$

Hence $\Vert a+b \Vert \leq \Vert a \Vert + \Vert b \Vert$

This bound will be met when $\langle a,b \rangle = \Vert a \Vert \Vert b \Vert$. This happens when $a = \lambda b$ with $\lambda \geq 0$ according to a corollary to Cauchy-Schwartz inequality.

Comment: To make your answer look a bit prettier you can use \Vert instead of $||$ and \langle, \rangle instead of $<, >$. Also, it is Schwarz, not Schwartz.

Comment: Updated with ur suggestion.

Comment: So pretty :D +1

Comment: And next time write names with large initials.